# Find a div which not equals this class

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to change the background color of those div-s, which does not have Size class. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .RedBox {
            background-color:pink;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

        .Size {
            font-size: 36pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div class="Size">
        lorem ipsum
    </div>

    <div>
        lorem ipsum
    </div>              
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean to include some javascript?

Comment: @Peter Ruzsin, You just need set *not* selector of javascript for your resolution. please see my below post which help you to get resolution.

Comment: $('div:not(.Size)').css('background-color','red')   this will help you to apply css which div does not contain *Size* class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    var arrDivs = document.querySelectorAll('DIV:not(.Size)'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < arrDivs.length; i++)
    {
        arrDivs[i].classList.add('RedBox');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('div').not('.Size').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('div:not(.Size)').css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    .RedBox {
      background-color: pink;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    
    .Size {
      font-size: 36pt;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    lorem ipsum
  </div>

  <div class="Size">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>

  <div>
    lorem ipsum
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```